# how to get the saved password from android studio 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I forgot the keystore password key password. But it is saved in android studio. Is there any option to retrieve this.

Inside /.gradle/6.5/executionHistory/executionHistory.bin I am getting signingConfig.signingConfigData.storePasswordHash. Is there anything I can do to get the password ?

Android version used 4.1

gradle version used 6.5

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-keystore-password-recover/wikis/HowTo.wiki

Comment: Inside /.gradle/6.5/executionHistory/executionHistory.bin I am getting signingConfig.signingConfigData.storePasswordHash. Is there anything I can do to get the password ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to :

[image]

And then command + f (in mac) / Cntrl + f (Windows) and search for `signingConfig.storePassword`

Comment: can't find the text signingConfig.storePassword in executionHistory.bin

Comment: found the keyword signingConfigData.storePasswordHash.Is there any way to find the password from this?

Comment: Have you created the apk? First create an apk using the password stored in Android studio then check the build folder and look for `executionHistory.bin` and there's the password

Comment: yes.I have creaed the apk. showing  signingConfigData.storePasswordHash only.please help me

Comment: Inside /.gradle/6.5/executionHistory/executionHistory.bin I am getting signingConfig.signingConfigData.storePasswordHash. Is there anything I can do to get the password ?

Comment: Can't you see the password there? should be there with the alias and more information

Comment: No .I can't see the password. I have searched the keyword signingConfig.storePassword .But not found the word. Only getting the keyword signingConfigData.storePasswordHash.